# find a string in a file, change the next line by extracting data from another file using Python

Tags: python, file

There are two files file1 and file2. I'm taking input from the user and saving it into file1 and the file2 has data in it (it is a config file). I have a few fields in file1 which are same as in file2.

I have to find a particular field in file2 and modify the data in the next line of that field and the data that needs to go there is the data from file1.

Example: file1.txt has

```
ABCD: 1.2.3.4    
EFGH: 2.3.4.5   
IJKL: 3.4.5.6
```

file2.ini has

```
[ABCD]  
ipaddr = 9.8.7.6
```

I need to find `ABCD` and insert `1.2.3.4` in the `ipaddr` field of `[ABCD]` in file2.

```
file1 = open(path,'r+')
filedata1 = file1.read()
file1.close() 
newdata1 = filedata1.replace("abcd","efgh")
file1 = open(path,"w")
file1.write(newdata1)  
file1.close()
```

I can do the regular find and replace by using above code, but cannot implement it in my scenario. Any hint will also be sufficient.

Comment: Would file2 then have two entries under [ABCD] or would it replace the current entry?

Comment: no, file2 will not have 2 entries. It will have a single entry under [ABCD], meaning it would replace the ipaddr field in the ABCD with the user entered ipaddr in file1 as reference.

Comment: Have you looked at [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)? You can read your ini file, overwrite fields from file1, and then resave it.

Comment: I tried using argparser, but that requires user specifying all the values on the command line when he passes the command to execute the program but it would be a mess if there are many arguments to be passed. Same is the case with configparser I feel.